can't get exwm working
I thought I'd try exwm. I installed /usr/share/xsessions/emacs.desktop as described in the documentation. I installed xelb, and exwm from the arch aur. I put the recommended additions to my ~/.emacs.d/init.el including
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/xelb/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/exwm/")
and the other stuff recommended in the manual, including:
(exwm-enable).
Then if I logout, and login again after choosing EmacsWM from the gdm list of options, I see an emacs window in the top left of my screen saying:
Warning (initialization): An error occured while loading '/home/myself/.emacs.d/init.el':
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or director, compat
I did create a .xinitrc as recommended too, though I suspect it isn't used when starting from gdm... because other apps I try and open there don't show up.
I guess it didn't load exwm because M-x exwm-reset is not found.
What should I do?

Looks like you need to install the 'compat' library.  Do M-x package-install RET compat RET.
